# How to disable buttons except the one that match your session key

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am making a page where the user has a login with a session key that matches his username. I want to disable buttons in the last column of a table which doesn't match the session.

My table looks like this : [image: table]

I would like to disable the 'Delete' buttons of the rows where field "User" does not match with the session key. It's a simple plain text username/password used for the session *(i know, for now its ok)*

Here is my PHP script : http://codepad.org/wotpO7Mu

*(I know I am not using PDO, and this method of fetching values is deprecated.)*

I created my login session this way : https://krisnaordinary.wordpress.com/2010/04/24/creating-a-simple-login-logout-session-using-php/

Can you please help me edit/fix my code to have fields for which I am echo -ing the buttons to be disabled except the one for which the session $_SESSION['usr'] matches the field $row['user_ID'] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding [`disabled`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp) attribute in the button if your session doesn't match

```
$active = $_SESSION['User'] == $row['user_id'];
echo "<td>".
       "<button class='btn' type='submit' id='1'".
          ($active ? "" : "disabled").">".
          "Delete".
       "</button>".
     "</td>";
```

I have also went ahead and simplified your code, you don't have to have two buttons, `input type=submit` is same as `button type=submit`. You can also have alternate quotes (double inside single or single inside double) to have a cleaner code.

Comment: What if user access delete url directly from URL bar ??

Comment: Having a button inside button will not solve that issue in any way!! You have to restrict that in your `delete` handler

Comment: Thank-you so much. That worked @GopikrishnaS. I owe you one. :)

Comment: @GopikrishnaS: How do I add an `onclick=` to call a function for my Delete button? I want to only delete the record from my database for the row which I am able to click the delete button. Can you help?

Comment: It has to be handled by a javascript code in the front end, you cannot do it in php (you can but I'd recommend _against_ it). Remove `type=submit` from the button to prevent auto submitting the form. Use a library like jQuery to query all the buttons and add a listener for click event. Store the row id in an attribute from php, so when querying from javascript you can get that id. Do some research on [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) calls, to delete the item from the listener.